# Large Nested Document In MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Imagine you have a collection of items (say A) around 50,000 but every item in it (say a) has a nested collection which can be huge say 20 million items (say B and an item in is refereed to as b). How do you recommend saving this in Mongodb?

A--a-B--b

Should I save it as it like the above And have you huge nested collections or should I flatten out the collections and actually represent the nested collection and at extra attributes on that defines what each item (b) belong to (A)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have huge nested document, because there is a [limit in document size in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents#Documents-MaximumDocumentSize) (the link also gives good reasons why this limitation). So your documents inside collection nested inside **a** have to be into a separate collection and you should relate them somehow with **a**.